# How to save a bokeh gridplot as single file

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using bokeh (0.8.1) in combination with the ipython notebook to generate GridPlots. I would like to automatically store the generated GridPlots to a single png (hopefully pdf one day) on disk, but when using "Preview/Save" it cycles through all of the figures asking me to store them separately. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: use the function output_file() (instead of output_notebook)

Comment: but does this allow me to display the plot in the ipython notebook and  simultaneously store the file to disk?

Answer (score 2):

You can export plot layouts in the same manner that you can export individual plots:

```
from bokeh.io import export_png
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot

plots = gridplot([[plot_1, plot_2], [plot_3, plot_4]])
export_png(plots, filename='./path/to/file.png')
```

Note that there are additional dependencies per [bokeh documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html):

1. The selenium python library
2. A headless browser and driver (eg chromium and chromedriver)

Answer (score 0):

First you save your grid in an object, 
Let's say "a" the you confirms that "a" is a grid. Example

grid = bly.gridplot(graficas,ncols=3) # Here you save your grid
bpl.show(grid). # Here you show your grid

from bokeh.io import export_png # You need this library to export

## Exportar grid

export_png(grid, filename="your path/name.png")